# Can you conditionally handle proxy_redirect on NGINX?

Tags: nginx, wordpress, proxypass

I was having issues with requests like https://example.com/blog/blog-post being sent to upstream but then 404'ing at https://example.com/blog-post/.  The issue was the upstream server (Wordpress) was issuing a 301 from /blog-post to /blog-post/.  Notice the '/' at the end of the redirected URL.   To correct this issue I added this line to my Nginx config.

```
proxy_redirect https://example.com/ https://example.com/blog/;
```

This corrected the initial issue, but now when I attempt to login to the WordPress site from request https://example.com/blog/wp-admin/ I am redirected to https://example.com/blog/blog/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

I have the following statements in my wp-config.php file on the upstream server

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com/blog');

define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com/blog');

_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

I tried removing the last line in the wp-config.php file above and that did not correct the issue.  Likewise when I remove the proxy_redirect line from my Nginx config the initial issue comes back.

I'm new to Nginx and from what I understand what I'm attempting to do with the proxy_redirect really should be handled by default I thought, however it only handles properly when it's in there but then it messes with my login to wordpress.  Any ideas how to correct?  Like can I have Nginx only process the proxy_redirect when 'blog/' is not in the redirected URI?

Here is my current Nginx config

```
map $uri $expires {
    default off;
    ~\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ 7d;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com/current/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/454191/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/454191/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        expires $expires;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ^~ /blog/ {
        #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 last;
        proxy_pass https://blog.example.com/;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect https://example.com/ https://example.com/blog/;

    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What was done to the WordPress installation and why?

Comment: I could not get the Wordpress site to redirect to the login without the addition of this line in wp-config.php 

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

Comment: Was that after you put in the `proxy_redirect`?

Comment: That was before the proxy_redirect.

Comment: Hm, that doesn't make much sense. Neither that line of PHP code nor the proxy_redirect should be present at all. I would start by removing them, seeing what problem (if any) remains, and then fixing that.

Comment: After removing the PHP code and the proxy_redirect, I'm getting something that looks to be constant but still unsure how to resolve.  Now when I attempt to request https://example.com/blog/blog-post it ends up redirecting to https://example.com/blog-post/ (404).  Likewise when attempting to login with request to https://example.com/blog/wp-admin/ I get the login page, then give credentials and get redirected to https://example.com/wp-admin/ (404) . In both cases it's like Nginx doesn't know to keep the '/blog/path' it's just trying '/path'

Comment: I think I may have solved this issue.  I added this to the wp-config.php.  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'example.com/blog';